# Comparing files within folders and moving files not found in one folder to a different location

Tags: file, powershell, directory

I am working on folders that contain many types and sizes of files within them. What I want to do is move files that are not contained in one folder into a new folder. I have embedded a picture link that helps illustrate what I am aiming to do.

[image]

I would like `test123.pdf` to be moved to a new location because it's not contained within the other folder. Below I have some code that simply compares the contents of each folder and outputs which file is out of place. I have been researching some things online, but have come up empty. Can anyone help me proceed?

Disclaimer: I know the path is wrong, but I can't show it for security reasons.

```
$Folder1 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "Enter Path here"
$Folder2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "Enter the Path here"

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Folder1 -DifferenceObject $Folder2
```

Comment: id be testing for file names explicitly if tats the only criteria

Comment: Two flat folders, or can there be files in subfolders as well? Where are the files supposed to go? Do you want unique files from each folder copied, or just from one of the folders?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to compare the contents of two folders, ID the file(s) that are not present in both folders, and then move them to a third folder.  To accomplish this, you can define your 2 paths in variables, compare the contents of the folders, grab the full path names of the different items, and then move them to the new destination.

```
$path1 = yourfirstpath
$path2 = yoursecondpathforcomparing
$path3 = yourdestinationpath

diff (ls $path1 -recurse) (ls $path2 -recurse) | ForEach {$_.InputObject.FullName} | Move-Item -Destination $path3
```

diff = Compare-Object , ls = Get-ChildItem

Comment: Will this break in the case of `c:\test\folder1\sub1\file.txt` and `c:\test\folder2\sub2\file.txt` - they are two unique files in unique paths which should both be copied out, but diff will see them as matching names, and neither will be copied?

Comment: This code works for the basic example above.  Now, if we get into moving folders that are not present in both locations, that would probably get dicey.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work, any file that is not in both Folder1 & Folder2 will be moved to Folder 3

```
$Folder1 = 'C:\folder1'
$Folder2 = 'C:\folder2'
$Folder3 = 'C:\folder3'

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Recurse $Folder1)
{
    if (-not(Test-Path "$Folder2\$file"))
        {
        Move-Item $file.FullName $Folder3
        }
}
```

Comment: It might be workable code for what @Zach Smith wants to do, but it does not do what you say it does; A file only in Folder2 "is not in both Folder1 & Folder2" but will not be moved to Folder3.

Answer (score 0):

This will compare by file name, and maintain the directory structure the extra files were found in, and handle the recursion properly.  The output of the code demonstrates the directory structure I tested with.

```
# be explict here to ensure everything is lowercase
# so when this is cut and pasted, it does not break
# when you enter the real path
$d1 = "d:\test\one".ToLower()
$d2 = "d:\test\two".ToLower()

$f1 = gci -Recurse $d1 -File | % {$_.FullName.ToLower()}
$f2 = gci -Recurse $d2 -File | % {$_.FullName.ToLower()}

"f1"
$f1
"`nf2"
$f2

$same = @()
$extra = @()
foreach ($f in $f2)
{
    $f2tof1path = $f.Replace($d2, $d1)
    if ($f1.Contains($f2tof1path) -eq $false) 
    {
        $extra += $f
    }
    else {
        $same += $f
    }
}

"`nSame"
$same

"`nExtra"
$extra

"`nMOVE"
$folder3 = "d:\test\three"
foreach ($f in $extra) 
{
    # move files somewhere, create dir if not exists
    $dest = $f.Replace($d2,$folder3)
    $destdir = $(Split-Path -Parent -Path $dest)
    if (!(Test-Path $destdir))
    {
        # remove quotes to do new-item, keep them to show what it will do
        "New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destdir"
    }
    # remove quotes to do move-item, keep them to show what it will do
    "Move-Item $f $dest"
}
```

*Output*

```
f1
d:\test\one\1.txt
d:\test\one\2.txt
d:\test\one\sub\1.txt
d:\test\one\sub\2.txt

f2
d:\test\two\1.txt
d:\test\two\2.txt
d:\test\two\3.txt
d:\test\two\sub\1.txt
d:\test\two\sub\2.txt
d:\test\two\sub\3.txt

Same
d:\test\two\1.txt
d:\test\two\2.txt
d:\test\two\sub\1.txt
d:\test\two\sub\2.txt

Extra
d:\test\two\3.txt
d:\test\two\sub\3.txt

MOVE
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path d:\test\three
Move-Item d:\test\two\3.txt d:\test\three\3.txt
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path d:\test\three\sub
Move-Item d:\test\two\sub\3.txt d:\test\three\sub\3.txt
```

If this does not solve your problem, it should get you 99% there.  Play around with the code, have fun, and good luck.